# Capistrano deploy permission problem

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to use `Capistrano 2.5.19` to deploy my `Sinatra` application. So far, I managed to successfully run `deploy:setup`, but when I try to perform the actual deployment or the check (`deploy:check`), Capistrano tells me that I don't have permission. I'm using sudo since I log in with my own user and the user used for deployment is called `passenger` and is member of the group `www-data`. Therefore is set `:runner` and `:admin_runner` to `passenger`. It seems, however, that Capistrano is not using `sudo` during the deployment, while it was definitively doing so during the setup (`deploy:setup`). Why is that? I thought that the user specified by the `runner` parameter is used for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot directly answer your questions, however, I would like to offer up a different solution, which is to take the time to properly set up ssh/rsa keys to accomplish what you want to do. This will allow you to both not worry about setting and changing users in addition to not having to worry about embedding authentication information inside your cap scripts.

Comment: That doesn't really help me. We have multiple users that are members of a certain group. Members of this group are allowed to perform deployments by `sudo`-ing (without password) to the non-priveliged passenger user. I really don't want to allow `passenger` to log in to the system. Furthermore, I don't want to maintain a `authorized_keys2` file for the `passenger` user.